# Manifold arising from particular proof of Hairy Ball Theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

**Background, aka considerations to find my actual question**

In Geometry three, at the end of the last lesson, we sketched a proof of the famous [Hairy Ball Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem). The proof goes as follows.

**Lemma:**
The fundamental group of $SO(3)$ is $\mathbb{Z}_2$, i.e. the cyclical group of order 2.

That follows from a homeomorphism that can be found between $SO(3)$ and the projective plane $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{R})$. This is achieved by realizing the projective plane as a quotient of $S^2\times[0,\pi]$ by identifying $S^2\times\{0\}$ to a point (thus getting a full sphere $D^3$) and then identifying antipodal points on $\partial D^3$, i.e. $(v,\pi)\sim(-v,\pi)$, and then finding a countinuous map from $S^2\times[0,\pi]$ to $SO(3)$ and seeing that taking the quotient makes it a homeomorphism since the identifications identify its fibers and the resulting inverse function is continuous.

The hairy ball theorem is then "proved" by finding a homeomorphism between the set $U$ of pairs $(x,v)\in TS^2$ with $|v|=1$ and $SO(3)$, which is a diffeomorphism, and then using a field $X$ which contradicts the theorem to produce a normalization and then a homeomorphism between $S^2\times S^1$ and $U$. This would mean $S^2\times S^1$ is homeomorphic to $SO(3)$, but the latter has fundamental group of order 2 and the former has fundamental group $(\mathbb{Z},+)$, so they can't be homeomorphic.

The first homeomorphism follows. The given function is $f(A)=(Ae_1,Ae_2)$. That it takes values in $U$ is since the columns of an orthogonal matrix $A$ form an orthonormal basis so $Ae_1,Ae_2$, which are the first two columns, are orthogonal and have norm 1, thus forming a pair in $U$, modulo moving $Ae_2$ from the origin to the "tip" of $Ae_1$ (i.e. to $Ae_1$ if we view it as a point rather than a vector). Continuity is obvious, since the components of the image are vectors of components of the matrix. That it is surjective is clear, as every pair $(x,v)$ can be completed to a base with the vector product $x\wedge v$, giving us the columns of an orthogonal matrix. By construction, $f$ maps that matrix to the starting pair. So this is the inverse, which is continuous, since the first two columns are the pair and the third is a continuous function of the pair. Injectivity is then obvious. Also, the components are polynomials in the matrix's entries, so they are smooth, and the inverse is also smooth for the same reason.

The second homeomorphism follows. Taken a pair $(x,e^{i\theta})\in S^2\times S^1$, we use the normalized field $X$ to build the matrix $(x,\cos\theta X(x),\sin\theta x\wedge X(x))$. In any case the images of such a map are triplets of orthogonal vectors, and since $X$ is normalized they would make a nice orthogonal matrix, except they evidently are not normalized. I'm guessing I mistyped and the second comma was meant to be a plus. Since $x,X(x)$ are orthogonal and normalized, their vector product is too, so $\cos\theta X(x)+\sin\theta x\wedge X(x)$ gives a tangent vector, which is normalized since $X(x)\perp x\wedge X(x)$ and they are normalized, and their coefficients are sine and cosine of the same angle, thus having squares that sum to 1. Taking a pair $(x,v)$, I can decompose $v$ into its component parallel to $X(x)$ and "the rest", which will have to be parallel to $x\wedge X(x)$ since it has to stay orthogonal to $x$ and be orthogonal to $X(x)$. $v$ is normalized, so the coefficients of $X(x)$ and $x\wedge X(x)$ in the above decomposition will identify an angle. The pair $(x,e^{i\theta})$, with $\theta$ being that angle, maps to $(x,v)$ via $h$. So $h$ is bijective since we have its inverse. $h$ is continuous, since its first component is the first component of the starting pair and the other one is a combination of vectors obtained via continuous processes from $x$ (smooth processes in fact) thorough coefficients which are obtained from a chart on $S^1$, thus being smooth. I'm a bit concerned with the global definition of this chart thought: mapping $e^{i\theta}$ back to $\theta$ globally should give some continuity problems in 0. But we are not using $\theta$, rather the sine and cosines, which are the real and imaginary part of $e^{i\theta}$, so no problem, absolutely smooth. The inverse still seems reasonably smooth to me. So this is a diffeomorphism.

Oh, so no problem. Well, we are left with proving $U$ is a smooth manifold. Now after writing all this it seems a pity to just delete it, so I'll leave it as background and end with my actual question.

**Actual question at last**

> Let $U$ be the set of pairs $(x,v)\in TS^2$ (identifying the tangent bundle as the union of the planes tangent to $S^2$ as embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$) with $|v|=1$. How do I prove it is a submanifold of $TS^2$?

The suggestion given by the teacher was via a regular value, but I'm not sure what map to consider.

Comment: Nice question! When I was trying to understand the topology of $SO(3)$ I kept thinking that $SO(3)$ is $S^2 \times S^1$ because if you have and object in $3$-space then the the movement of its axis is paremetrized by $S^2$ and the rotation is parametrized by $S^1$.  In a sense this is correct, but it just proves that $SO(3)$ is **locally** $S^2 \times S^1$ and not globally. I think in a first course in algebraic topology this is a very subtle issue: For example, a teacher told us that since a point on a cylinder is characterized by a number and an angle the cylinder is $R \times S^1$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $f(x,v) = \|v\|^2$, $f\colon TS^2\to\Bbb R$, where $(x,v)\in S^2\times\Bbb R^3\subset\Bbb R^3\times\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Differential takes values in $\mathbb R$ so either zero or surjective, zero only in $v=0$, so critical points of $f$ in $\mathbb R^6$ are $\mathbb R^3\times\{0\}$ which doesn't intersect $U$, plus $U=f^{-1}(1)$ which is therefore regular value as the critical points all go to 0, hence $U$ is smooth manifold. Perfect.